# Convert picture to binary BASE64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I convert a picture to binary BASE64 and send it by post to another API to be saved?

It looks something like:

1. User imports a photo through the HTML form and it transforms it to binary BASE64 code:

   ```
   base64_encode = Base64.encode64(img_from_fild_form)
   ```
2. The data is sent to another API (media):

   ```
   options = { :auth_key=>01qw6, :post_id=>20, :base64_encode=>base64_encode }
   HTTParty.post('localhost:9000/save_image', options)
   ```

Comment: "binary BASE64" doesn't make sense because BASE64 is an ASCII encoding of either binary or text.

Answer (score 1):

if the input is from a rails form then it probably as easy as:

```
Base64.encode64(params[:key_for_file].read)
```

the uploaded file is likely an instance of [`ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html)

Comment: How to get instance of ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.
View:
`= file_field_tag :file`
Controller:
`upload = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new({
  :tempfile => File.new("ig.png")
})`

Comment: is this a question? You shouldn't need to manually instantiate it. The Rails params parser should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as easy as:

```
require 'base64'
base64_encoded = Base64.encode64(img_from_file_form)
```

Hope that helps. :)